# T-Sql join on row number

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[StartDateTime]
    ,[S_Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY a.[StartDateTime]
        )
    ,max(a.EndDateTime) [EndDateTime]
    ,b.StartDateTime [next_start]

FROM [BUR].[VisualMesa] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [StartDateTime]
        ,max(EndDateTime) [EndDateTime]
        ,[S_Index+1] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY [StartDateTime]
            ) + 1
    FROM [BUR].[VisualMesa]
    GROUP BY [StartDateTime]
    ) b ON a.[S_Index] = b.[S_Index+1]
GROUP BY a.[StartDateTime]
    ,b.StartDateTime
    ,b.[S_Index+1]
```

I'm trying to put the end time and next start time on the same row, but I can't figure out how to properly join the tables. I can't use a temporary table because power BI can't handle temporary tables (in direct query mode). If I could use a temporary table, the join would be simple, but since I can't use a temporary table (again because of power bi), I have gotten stuck. Help?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Sample data, with DDL, and expected results would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If power BI direct query would allow the use of a CTE

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS (
  SELECT 
    StartDateTime
  , MAX(EndDateTime) AS EndDateTime
  , S_Index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime)
  FROM [BUR].[VisualMesa]
  GROUP BY StartDateTime
)
SELECT 
  c1.StartDateTime
, c1.EndDateTime
, c1.S_Index
, c2.StartDateTime AS next_start
FROM CTE_DATA c1
LEFT JOIN CTE_DATA c2 ON c2.S_Index = c1.S_Index+1
```

But using `LEAD` simplifies this.

```
SELECT 
  StartDateTime
, MAX(EndDateTime) AS EndDateTime
, S_Index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime)
, next_start = LEAD(StartDateTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime)
FROM [BUR].[VisualMesa]
GROUP BY StartDateTime
```

Comment: I forget to mention that CTE doesn't work with power bi direct query. But your suggestion for Lead worked. thanks!